# Integrating Cognito Directly with 3rd Party API

Tags: amazon-cognito, openid-connect, federated-identity

I had always thought that to integrate between Cognito and another IdP, Cognito would basically reroute any user actions (like creating an account and updating your profile) back to some interface provided by the IdP. This is my understanding of how "federated authentication" works.
[image]

But the developers from the 3rd party we're integrating with say we should be able to make calls to Cognito - even for things like updating profile information - and have Cognito "federate" those calls to their API. Is this true? If it is, how would you actually accomplish that?

[image]

- Note that the 3rd party IdP has a user interface to perform all actions like account creation, login, and view/edit profile, but they also expose a NextIdentity API for direct API calls.

Answer (score 0):

**FEDERATED AUTHENTICATION**

This involves the authorization server (AS) handling a `code flow` via an Identity Provider (IDP), as you describe.

**USER STORAGE**

A user's main account for your applications is created in the AS. This might occur when the user first authenticates, or in some setups the user might be provisioned by an administrator.

The user will also exist in the IDP, and your AS may or may not have permissions to update it. Eg if Google sign in is used as the IDP, you probably won't have access to update the account, since it belongs to the end user and not the owner of the AS.

**USER MANAGEMENT APIs**

Both AS and IDPs should provide these. They might then be called when `User Management` or `Edit Profile` screens are used within your applications. This would enable your apps to save user data to both data sources at once.

The standard option is a [SCIM API](https://curity.io/resources/learn/user-management/), though some providers may offer other options such as a [GraphQL API](https://curity.io/resources/learn/graphql-user-management/), for user friendly app integration.[Cognito User Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/managing-users.html) is pretty basic though, with limited API support.

**SUMMARY**

User management APIs such as SCIM should be provided for each system, with calls triggered from your own backend APIs. In all cases you should be able to update the AS account details.

In scenarios where you also own the IDP data, you should be able to update that as well. This call will not be triggered from the AS, but from your own backend APIs.